# store API response in Angular application

Tags: angular

I have an endpoint that returns some site configuration that I want to use in different components.

```
  getSiteConfig() {
    return this.http.get('/json/siteConfig')
  }
```

I can call this endpoint like:

```
this.siteService.getSiteConfig()
.subscribe(response => {
   this.supportedLangs = response.languages;
   .... etc
})
```

The values from this endpoint are not going to change so I dont really want to use ngrx store. and are needed in different components, so I dont want to make an API call for each component.

What is the best approach to have this config always available for different components to use?

**EDIT**

I am currently using this method that seems to be working:

- in service:

  `public siteconfig = new BehaviorSubject(null);`
  getSiteConfig() {

  ```
  this.http.get('/json/siteConfig')
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.siteconfig.next(response);
  })
  ```

  }

And then in the components I use:

```
this.storeService.siteconfig.filter(val => val !== null)
.subscribe(res => this.availableLanguages = res.languages);
```

Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you hear about resolvers ?

You could create a resolver which will send an HTTP request only if its local variable is not already set. For example:

In you routing file :

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'firstPath',
    component: FirstComponent,
    resolve: {
        VariableName: MyResolverService
    }

},
{
    path: 'secondPath',
    component: SecondComponent,
    resolve: {
        ***VariableName***: MyResolverService
    }
}, ...]
```

This will call your resolver each time you're navigating to the selected path, and call the resolver function before the component is built.

In your resolver:

```
    @Injectable()
export class MyResolverService implements Resolve<any> {

    private _supportedLangs: any;

    constructor(private _siteService: SiteService) { }

    resolve (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        if (!this._supportedLangs)
           return this._siteService.getSiteConfig().map(result => {
               console.log(result);
               this._supportedLangs = result;
           });
        return this._supportedLangs;
    }
}
```

You can get the value within the components you want like this:

In FirstComponent for example:

```
this.supportedLangs = this._route.snapshot.data['***VariableName***'];
```

Comment: `if (!this._supportedLangs)` where are you defining that `this._supportedLangs`?

Comment: Just above look again, I'm declaring private _supportedLangs which should be same type as your "response.languages"

Comment: Yes you are declaring it, but not initializing it? when you come to that (!this.supportedLangs) it will always be false, so it will always make the getSiteConfig http request. And I dont want that.

Comment: Oops you're right, in the .map funciton you have to add this._supportedLangs = result;

Comment: This way you will do a request on the API once.

Comment: And return your _supportedLangs

Comment: Does providing this service in multiple components ensures that the `this._supportedLangs` keeps its value everytime the resolver is injected?

Comment: The resolver is built once. This configuration ensure that before loading the comoponent, you will get the value. If you store the value in the service , it will be kept. Lets try with some console.log

Comment: Lets put console log in your SiteService in the getSiteConfig() method: if your console log is called twice then it does'nt work

Comment: Thanks i'll give it a try.